# Replicating Dev environment from one EC2 machine to another

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, vagrant, amazon-ami

So, I have been running into this problem constantly --

I usually spin up EC2 machines temporarily for running some benchmarks or small projects and then shut them down when the work is done.

However, everytime I spin up a new machine, I have to setup my environment all over again.

Here are the things I want to be configured easily:

1. I have a custom .vimrc, .tmux.conf, .zshrc file that I need to be setup
2. I have to re-install all the basic packages on ubuntu
3. I have to re-install all the vim plugins
4. Some times partitin/format the harddisk and do other sys-admin work.

I've used Docker before but I find Docker to be more invasive for what I need. It's an additional software that I've to run and I have to mount filesystems, setup extra networking bridge for that, configure ssh-in and ssh-out for etc. So I would like to avoid Docker if possible for this.

I think Vagrant has similar problems.

I am wondering if I should just create an EC2 AMI for this. Is that the best solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just dump your configuration to a S3 bucket and get it back. you can also create init scripts on your machines to install them as you like (or fetch data directly as you need).  you can even get more advanced but i guess its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options you could use.

One option is to **create a startup script** that installs everything you like. You can then launch new machines that are fully configured. However, it takes a bit of work to get the script right.

Another option is to **Stop the instance** when not in use and start it later. You won't be charged for EC2, but you will be charged for the EBS volume storage.

Or, you could **create an AMI** of the instance, then launch a new instance later from the AMI. This can be slightly cheaper because the AMI only keeps the storage blocks that are in-use and AMI/snapshot storage is cheaper than EBS storage.